# Conditional Independence, Bayes Network and d-separation

Tags: conditional-probability, independence, bayesian-network

I have a diagram of a Bayes network as shown below:
[image: Bayes Network of a person catching a train]

$$\begin{array}{c}A&&&&B&&&&C\\&\searrow&&\swarrow\\&&D&&&&E\\&&&\searrow&&\swarrow\\&&&&F\end{array}$$

The only independence assumptions between the random variables A to F are those enforced by the shape of this network.

The professor said that "conditioned on D, we have A is conditionally independent of B".

But from what I have read and learnt from $d$-separation, wouldn't that be incorrect? Since $d$-separation states that if we have a path $X\rightarrow Y\leftarrow Z$, $X$ is guaranteed to be independent of $Z$ if $Y$ and its descendents are not in the evidence set, i.e. they are not been conditioned on.

So $A$ is only independent of $B$ if $D$ and $F$ is not conditioned on?

Could the answer for this be confirmed please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $D$ is a common effect of nodes $A$ and $B$.  Its presence in the conditioning set will block the only path between them.  They are not d-separated.

Still, this *does not* prohibit them from being conditionally independent.
*D-separation entails conditional independence*, but conditional independence does not need d-separation.

However, the graph *alone* is **not enough** to proclaim that the nodes *are* conditionally independent.  Are there any attached tables the professor may be using to say so?

Comment: The only independence assumptions between the random variables A to F are those enforced by the shape of this network. 
I will edit the question to reflect this. Sorry!

Comment: What does F have to do with It?